# How to control sequence of multiple flows from a single event

Tags: ssis, control-flow, operator-precedence

In Control flow I have defined a flow where one event leads to multiple events.
e.g.

[image]

What I am finding is that there is no consistency in the order in which tasks are executed. Sometimes task 2 will execute before the loop container tasks, but other times the loop container tasks will execute before task 2.
If I have a dependency, for example task 2 references a file that task 3 is going to delete, then I want task 2 to execute first every time.
I know I could create a flow where task 3 has precedent condition based on successful completion of task 2, but in this particular scenario task 2 has a precedent condition defined based on task 1 and may not meet the condition every time, whereas the loop container will execute every time.
So how do I go about making sure that task 2 (when it does meet the condition) executes before the loop container?

Answer (score 0):

**This might work in your case:**

Place `TASK3` after `TASK2`

Add you your condition in the precedence constraint editor

[image]

Write your condition in the Expression. If it meet the conditon then it would go further.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constraint between task2 and task3, then change this constraint to a Logical Or condition.  This means that task3 will execute after task1 completes OR after Task 2 completes.

Here is a mock up:

[image]

Here is the constraint setting:
[image]

Comment: I applied this change, with one addition. The constraint for task 1 means it only fires on the last day of any given month, so I added an expression to the constraint between script task and task 2 to be the opposite of that i.e. it fires on any day that IS NOT the last day of a month. This results in flow going only one of two ways.
Thanks for this tip. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Sequence Containers were designed to handle. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140346(v=sql.105).aspx